# Swift how to make uicollectionviewcell's height change based on content

Tags: swift

I have got this Swift code

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0), 
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collectionView.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width-30, height: 50)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 5, bottom: 15, right: 5)
}
```

My goal is to make cell's height automatic based on it's content.I wanted to implement
`self.flowLayout.estimatedSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`,but i didn't know what `flowLayout` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get flowLayout:

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) //use auto layout for the collection view
}
```

You can do something like this:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to change `let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())` to `let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)`

Comment: It is not necessary because this code only changes estimatedItemSIze but is it working only with UICollectionViewFlowLayout() ?

Comment: Yes or you can do something like in my updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately this code shows a square 207 by 207,i tried your code also it didn't have any results neither did `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`